# How to disable sentence-level auto correction in SpeechRecognition Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

when I speak a sentence 'show **tenet** movie near me' automatically the speech recognition API changing my sentence to 'show **tonight** movie near me' the problem was the word **tenet** is changed to **tonight**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the alternatives? You can set maxAlternatives to something high like 20, then use a function such as this to check if one of them contains the phrase you're looking for.

Pass your phrases as an array and the results received from SpeechRecognition.

```
function ExtractTranscript(phrases, results) {
  // Loop through the alternatives to check if any of our phrases are contained in them.
  for (let result in results[0]) {
    if (new RegExp(phrases.join("|")).test(results[0][result].transcript)) {
      return results[0][result].transcript; // Return the alternative if they are
    }
  }
  return results[0][0].transcript; // Otherwise return the one with the highest confidence
}
```

This does also rely on the word "tenet" being in the vocabulary of the API.